# HTTP requests differ between browsers

Tags: json, angularjs, api, safari, xmlhttprequest

First of, I'm not really sure how to title this one correctly or how to describe "enough" of the problem to make it understandable.

Anyhow, I've got a wordpress installation running that serves as a back-end to a blog. It has a json-api-plugin installed. To this I've added a Angular-based front-end that sends HTTP-requests, using jQuery's $.ajax(), to the back-end.

Now, it runs perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox (haven't tried IE, I'm on a Mac). But in Safari I've run into a bit of a problem. It seems some requests work, while others dont't.

For example, a request to `http://api.walander.se/json/get_posts/?page=1` works perfect in all three browsers (This is also the only one I've gotten to work in Safari). While, a request to `http://api.walander.se/json/get_category_index` works in Chrome and Firefox but fails in Safari.

The error message as given in Safaris inspector-tool is given below

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (get_category_index, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.walander.se/json/get_category_index/. Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (walander.se, line 0)
```

All requests that fails in Safari give the same error message.

If I enter the example url from above directly in Safari it works given the expected response.

```
{"status":"ok","count":2,"categories":[{"id":3,"slug":"development","title":"Development","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":1},{"id":2,"slug":"web","title":"Web","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":1}]}
```

Below I present some code examples that might help understanding my problem.

This is my Angular-RequestService that handles all HTTP-requests to the server:

```
app.service('requestService',function() {
    var API = 'http://api.walander.local/api/';

    this.send = function( type , service , dataIn , successCallback, errorCallback , loadingInfo ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: service,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: type,
            data: dataIn,
            timeout: 10000,
            beforeSend: function() {
                if ( loadingInfo != undefined ) 
                    wLoading(loadingInfo.div,loadingInfo.text);
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                successCallback(data);
            },
            error: function(data , jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("ERROR: Service failed, unable to get response");
                console.log("ERROR: textStatus: " + textStatus);
                console.log("ERROR: errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                errorCallback(data);
            },
            complete: function() {
                if ( loadingInfo != undefined ) 
                    wRemoveLoading(loadingInfo.div);    
            }   
        });
    }
    this.get = function( service , dataIn , successCallback , errorCallback , loadingInfo ) {
        this.send( 'GET' , API+service , dataIn , successCallback , errorCallback , loadingInfo );
    }
    this.post = function( service , dataIn , successCallback , errorCallback , loadingInfo ) {
        this.send( 'POST' , API+service , dataIn , successCallback , errorCallback , loadingInfo );
    }  
});
```

Both the example url:s above are of GET-type which means that I use the reqeustService.get()-function.

Below is an example of how I use the requestService to request the current page and a list of categories from the API:

```
app.service('blogService',function( requestService ) {
    this.getPage = function( page , refreshBlog ) {
        requestService.get( 'get_posts/?page='+page , null , function(data) {
            handleResponse( data , refreshBlog , "page " + page );
        } , function(data) {      

        } , { div: '#post-list' , text: 'Loading posts' } );   
    }

    this.getCategories = function( refreshCategories ) {
        requestService.get( 'get_category_index', null , function(data) {
            refreshCategories(data.categories);
        } , function(data) {

        } , { div: '#category-list', text: 'Loading categories' });
    }
... ( continued ) ...
};
```

However, I don't believe the error is in the Angular-code. I believe it has something to do with htaccess and HTTP-request-headers?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If u use angularjs - use its $http and $resource, not jquery for ajax. I recommend u to make page with 1 button that makes that problematic request (and use only angular, no jquery) -- then u can see clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'll start using the angular-js built-in version instead. However I don't understand what you mean with the button? How would that clarify the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky problem to solve. But I think I got it. =)

The reson for the error message below is that you do a request to 
`get_categpory_index/` you only accept the following encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch.

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (get_category_index, line 0)
```

This is the reason to the error message but fixing this will not fix your problem.

---

But why is some requests working and some are not? I did some investigation in firebug and I found that you are trying to fetch http://api.walander.se/json/get_category_index which is redirecting you to http://api.walander.se/json/get_category_index/. The second request has a different set of headers which cause the error.

The solution is to add an extra slash at the end of the url to avoid the redirect.

```
requestService.get( 'get_category_index/', null , function(data) {
```